# Annoying messages while running copy-item to a PSSession

Tags: powershell, copy, remote-server

I am copying some files to a server, using PowerShell 5 with copy-item and new-PSSession. The relevant lines in my script are (or that's what I think):

```
  $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $psCred ;
  Copy-Item $source -ToSession $session -Destination $target -Force;
```

My real script has a few copy-item calls more. When this script runs, I see messages flicker in the PS Window. When I run it from command line, they are in text-mode with a powershell-blue background; when I run it from the ISE, they are GUIfied and shown as a textbox. They disappear quickly, but the look like "Copying" and the name of the currently copied file. So, they are progresss messages.

But I want a silent copy. I didn't consciously activate some debug flag. How can I suppress the progress messages?

I tried to append | Out-Null to the Copy-Item. I tried -InformationAction SilentlyIgnore. I looked at PSSessionOption, found nothing that might help. I tried to search the net, but everybody seems to be asking for MORE messages, not less.

Comment: You can't.  The copy is utilizing a progress bar and isn't actual output.  This happens most noticeably on large files.

Comment: If it is progress, you could set `$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"`to suppress the progress display.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bruce, that solved it. If you'd post this as an answer, I will give you the "accept" mark for it.

Answer (score 1):

Per [comment by @Bruce Payette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334273/annoying-messages-while-running-copy-item-to-a-pssession#comment87696963_50334273):

- Set `$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` to suppress the progress display.

There are a bunch of other preference variables you can set as well: [PowerShell Preference Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7#progresspreference)